# Asking for M2 equivalence of M1 code

Tags: discussion

I see a rise of questions asking for M2 equivalent of M1 code.

I feel like those questions are asking for too much specially when the OP posts a big block of code.

Should I flag those questions or is that allowed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why shouldn't they be allowed?
but it depends on the question as always.
If the OP posts the code he wants to "translate" to M2 and the code is not a 10k lines file of custom code, it should definitely be OK.
Also, showing an understanding of what the OP wants "translated" also works.
Here is an example:

> "I used to add items to the main menu in M1 using the event
>   `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` but It does not work in M2.
>   How can I do that in M2?"

But questions like

> the grid system changed in admin from m1 to m2. How can move my m1 code to m2?

are not the best questions.
But you should not flag them. A simple close vote as "too broad" should be enough.
See [What should I flag and what I shouldn't flag](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1014/146) for more info about flags.

Comment: I agree. To add to your examples: Questions with a big block of code, a "how can I port this" with no sign of effort and little explanation are not even close-worthy: downvote, comment and move on